# Is it possible to host an own repository with Jenkins plugins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to host an own repository with Jenkins plugins?
E.g. to make them available in a closed down intranet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The simplest way to do it is likely to use [Juseppe](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/juseppe).

See [this blog post](https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/07/14/juseppe-a-custom-update-site-for-jenkins/) from the Jenkins site.